# Database field of timestamp type cannot be added to the database using hook_schema()

Tags: 8, database, datetime

I have created a custom module in drupal 8. But in the .install file there is a field for created_date which has a type of timestamp. When I try to enable that module it gives the below error.

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'created_date'' in
```

**.install file**

```
<?php
function golf_reservation_schema()
{
  $schema['golf_reservation'] = array(
   'fields' => array(
       'id' => array(
           'type'     => 'serial',
           'not null' => TRUE,
       ),
       'property_tid' => array(
           'type' => 'int',
           'not null' => TRUE,
       ),
       'property_name' => array(
           'type'     => 'varchar',
           'length'   => 100,
           'not null' => TRUE,
       ),
       'title' => array(
           'type'     => 'varchar',
           'length'   => 20,
           'not null' => FALSE,
       ),
       'full_name' => array(
           'type'     => 'varchar',
           'length'   => 255,
           'not null' => TRUE,
       ),
       'tee_date' => array(
           'type'     => 'varchar',
           'length'   => 255,
           'not null' => TRUE,
       ),
       'tee_time' => array(
           'type'     => 'varchar',
           'length'   => 255,
           'not null' => TRUE,
       ),
       'golfers' => array(
           'type'     => 'int',
           'not null' => TRUE,
       ),
       'no_of_carts' => array(
           'type'     => 'int',
           'not null' => TRUE,
       ),
       'special_request' => array(
           'type'     => 'text',
           'not null' => FALSE,
       ),
       'created_date' => array(
           'mysql_type' => 'timestamp',
           'not null' => true,
       ),
     ),
     'primary key' => array('id'),
   );

   return $schema;
}
```

But when I execute this query in database it does not give an error

```
CREATE TABLE eme_golf_reservation (
  `id` INT NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  `property_tid` INT NOT NULL, 
  `property_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  `title` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
  `full_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  `tee_date` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  `tee_time` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  `golfers` INT NOT NULL, 
  `no_of_carts` INT NOT NULL, 
  `special_request` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
  `created_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I am running the latest Drupal version with MySQL 5.6.30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to explicitly define the default value for those in the schema:

```
'created_date' => [
  'mysql_type' => 'timestamp',
  'not null' => FALSE,
  'default' => NULL,
],
```

For maximum portability, you can also define the types for other databases:

```
'created_date' => [
  'mysql_type' => 'timestamp',
  'pgsql_type' => 'timestamp',
  'sqlite_type' => 'datetime',
  'not null' => FALSE,
  'default' => NULL,
],
```

Look at `\Drupal\KernelTests\Core\Database\SchemaTest` for an example.  FWIW, code doesn't use that for timestamp/created/updated.  Those are field types and handled by the Field API.

Comment: But when I copy this module to another computer which has the same mySQL version as me, it works without any issue. (without explicitly defining the default value )

Comment: This solution works for me. 

What should I do if I want timestamp field to add CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on each record addition? 

something like this...

`created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

I am using 'default' => CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, but this doesn't work.

Thanks